# How can I split a list into smaller lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list like so:

```
[10,10,10,20,20,20,20,30,40,40,40]
```

I want to split into X amount of lists, where X = how many unique elements there are, in the case above there are 4. So I would want 4 lists like so:

```
[[10,10,10],[20,20,20,20],[30],[40,40,40]]
```

Might be a dumb question and there is an easy way to do this but any help is appreciated, language is python3.

Answer (score 0):

[itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does what you need, except it returns iterators instead of lists. Converting to lists is easy though:

```
[list(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(my_list)]
```